# iOS7 Strange behavior of UIPickerView with an UIImage as custom view, any official info?

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, uipickerview

I was following a tutorial on how to build a custom *picker* with an `UIPickerView` in *Sams Teach Yourself IOS6 Application Development in 24 hours* and I've noticed that simply returning an `UIImage` in `(UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view` method of the `UIPickerViewDelegate` does not work properly: the images do not appear correctly (they rotate on the spinning wheel but for example they disappear when they should move over the current selection's row). I've found a solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158319/ios7-uipickerview-doesnt-properly-display-custom-views-with-images) on *Stack Overflow* and it effectively works, but I'd like to know if this strange behavior appeared in *IOS 7* is due to a new way of using `UIPickerView` or if it is more a sort of bug.. I did not find anything useful in the official *API Reference* docs. Is there any official doc that is talking about the change in how we must return an `UIImageView` to be used in a `UIPickerView`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is 'No'. I also looked through the Release Notes for 7.0 & 7.1 and looked at the differences in the references for UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate, and UIView (among others) and couldn't find anything do explain why it behaves this way now and I couldn't find any changes to UIPickerView or anything it inherits from or conforms to that would explain it. (If there is something there that explains it then it was not immediately obvious to me.)

As far as I know, those are the only places that would have any official information on this.

I think the only way to know for sure whether this is deliberate or a bug is to report it.