# UIPickerView doesn't display the content on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a problem with my UIPickerView.  The content isn't displaying on the line.

.m

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;

} // End numberOfComponentsInPickerView

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{    
    return [items count];

} // End numberOfRowsInComponent

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
           viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component
          reusingView:(UIView *)view
{    
   return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];   
}
```

All the items are connected properly.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data do you have in pickerData? The method you're using (pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:) needs to return a UIView. If pickerData contains strings, then you should be using pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:.

Comment: I changed it to pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent: and i-> return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row]; but the Picker is empty ..
Also when i changed it to IOS 6 its working Good .

Comment: Also i found this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158319/ios7-uipickerview-doesnt-properly-display-custom-views-with-images

But There is Self.myimage --- But all the images are on pilst.com.
So how can i pull them ...

Comment: @user3666781  What type of data is in pickerData?

Comment: the type is NSArray- 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerData;

Comment: @user3666781 what I asked is what kind of data is *in* dataPicker, not what its type is. Do you have strings in there, images, what?